# Mongock failed: NoClassDefFoundError org/springframework/data/mongodb/MongoDatabaseFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongock

I'm using the following pom in my spring boot app:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.13.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /><!-- resolve parent from repository, refer to http://www.tomitribe.com/blog/2016/06/i-do-not-hate-apache-maven/ -->
  </parent>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongock-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongock-spring-v5</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.cloudyrock.mongock</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-springdata-v3-driver</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

when I run the app with `java -jar my-app.jar` I got the following error:

```
NoClassDefFoundError org/springframework/data/mongodb/MongoDatabaseFactory
```

but when I run the app with `-noverify` it seems everything ok

please, someone can assist me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's due to incompatible versions.

As you can see in this [compatibility table](https://www.mongock.io/compatibility-versions-table), the version of Mongock you are using is compatible with spring-data 3.x, but you are using 2.x instead.

Mongock provides two drivers for spring-data, mongodb-springdata-v3-driver, for spring-data 3.x and mongodb-springdata-v2-drver for spring-data 2.2.X

I have a couple of suggestions:

1. Either upgrade your spring-data dependency to 3.x, or use mongodb-springdata-v2-drver(first one recommended)
2. Use dependency management so you don't need to specify the version for each dependency. You can do it for spring and for [Mongock](https://www.mongock.io/quick-start)

With that you should fix your issue ;)